# A character gives integer as output if we input an integer into it but this doesn't happen when an integer is assigned to it. Why?

Tags: c++, char, implicit-conversion

```
int p=89; //An integer defined and declared
    char g;   //A character defined
    g=p;      //Assigning the character the value of the integer p
    cout<<g;  //Here the output comes out to be "Y"
    cout<<endl<<"Enter any number";
    cin>>g;
    cout<<g;  //Here the output is coming out to be the integer you have inputted
```

Shouldn't it output an integer instead of giving `"Y"`? It is being assigned the value of an integer?

Comment: What is the input for `cin>>g;`?

Comment: You may input any integer, say 88.

Comment: whose output will be 8, not 88. Now do you understand why?

Comment: I just checked it by running..which has arised another question. Why it outputs 8 instead of 88?

Comment: Sir, can you please resolve my problem here? Or else I'll have to look up in the whole book.

Comment: Try this in both spots: `cout << g << ' ' << int(g);` This might prove illuminating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you assign an integer to the character variable, it reads the integer from the memory and store at its location and while interpreting that char value, it returns ASCII equivalent of it. While reading cin buffer into the character variable(char) it reads 1 byte of the char or its ASCII value in the memory and gives the output as ASCII equivalent of it.

Comment: Means that if I assign 66 to a character then it will output a character whose ASCII value is 66?(i.e B)

Comment: Yes It does print the character for the ASCII Value 66 that is B

Comment: If I input(not assign) 88 in the character and then output it, the output is 8 only, why not 88? char data type ranges from -128 to 127, so it should output 88.But it doesn't.

Comment: @DravitGupta because such input has 2 characters `8` and `8` but only the first character is being read since you read into a `char`. To read the whole input number, you would have to read it as an integer not as a character

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay, so what is the use of the range of char data type then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between an `int` and a `char`.

1. The size of an `int` variable is 4 (or 8) bytes depending on your machine, while `char` variable will be just 1 byte.
2. A `char` is implicitly convertible to an `int` due to *type promotion*.
3. Numbers have their ASCII equivalent characters.

So,

```
int p=89; //An integer defined and declared
char g;   //A character defined
g=p;      //Assigning the character the value of the integer p, which is 'Y' in ASCII - note single quotes
cout<<g;  //Here the output comes out to be 'Y'
cout<<endl<<"Enter any number";
cin>>g; // say 88, but since size of char is 1 byte, it only saves the first character, i.e., '8'
cout<<g; // prints '8' the character, not the integer
```

Comment: Why did you emphasise on single quotes?

Comment: because `char` - 1 byte of data, hence single quotes. Double quotes would mean it is a collection of char, i.e., `char[]`, or `char*`

Answer (score 0):

When you input something to the char g, you actually inputting a char instead of the ASCII value to it.

For example:

```
    char bar;
    cin>>bar;// assume you type 67
    cout<<bar;
```

the output will be 6 because 67 is not an integer number but 2 chars, and char bar can only hold up to 1 char, therefore, the output will be 6.